# how to import ml model (python) into another programming language

Tags: pickle, onnx, openvino, mlops

Can you explain which methods (pros and cons) are available in order to import ml-model
(sk-learn/tf/pytorch), etc into other code (java/c/C++) etc.

I mean that I want to take the pickle file (or something else) the binary python of the model and use it from different programming language
can i get using it better results? what else should I consider?
thanks

does "openvino / onnx" related?

I'm trying to understand which libraries are related

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two main parts in AI development. The first one is related to the Neural Network model development. This phase is usually done using Python language either for Tensorflow, Pytorch etc. Once the model is trained with optimized result, it will be converted into a binary (eg: .tf, .onnx). This file will be used in the inferencing phase.

The second phase is inferencing phase, where you need to utilize Neural Network model in its format for the use case that the model was trained for, such as license plate recognition. This part can be in any programming language that you find convenient. OpenVINO provides [IE samples](https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.2/openvino_docs_OV_UG_Samples_Overview.html) for this purpose.
The OpenVINO libraries allows you to use supported models from different platform/format such as ONNX/TF to be used on Intel hardware where those model's format need to be converted into OpenVINO format(IR).